# What is a good measure of self-regulation?

Tags: measurement, motivation, self-discipline

Is there self-regulation or self monitoring test. I am interested in measuring why people are not commited to their goals (quit smoking, dieting etc) so you can suggest another measure instead of self-regulation failure.

Comment: Both, and only the former applies. [Self-monitoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-monitoring) is a different construct. As for self-regulation, have you considered checking any of the references on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-control)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the Self-Regulation Questionnaire. [See here for a summary of the instrument](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcasaa.unm.edu%2Finst%2FSelfRegulation%2520Questionnaire%2520%28SRQ%29.pdf&ei=r1ONU9nINIXfkwWI84HIBw&usg=AFQjCNFFW-t3FvFD4CI1pS3zQSWyvUOuhQ&sig2=6SS-vDzfJIsxWwQeNk4KYg) in terms of what it purports measure, items, response scales, psychometric properties such as reliability and validity.

#### References

Brown, J. M., Miller, W. R., & Lawendowski, L. A. (1999). The Self-Regulation Questionnaire. In L. VandeCreek & T. L. Jackson (Eds.), Innovations in clinical practice: A source book (Vol. 17, pp. 281-289). Sarasota, FL: Professional Resource Press.

Comment: Looks pretty solid to me! I guess I'd prefer seven Likert rating options over the five they use, but otherwise, looks promising. Wish I had a nice big dataset to play around with, since they don't seem very clear on how to score it...A little MIRT analysis could fix that though! Saved it to my archive of measures for someday when the world is my respondent recruitment oyster...Thanks!

Comment: This questionnaire is exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a stop signal task that measure response inhibition. It has been associated with dependencies like smoking http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3077266/ and http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0018898 for a go/nogo task, though the stop signal task is preferred. There is also some studies linking inhibtion to self regulation and self control, although I dont remember the sources at the moment. Sorry for poor formatting, new here at s.e.

Comment: I agree with this approach insofar as the effects of such behavioral tasks typically exhibit less variability than questionnaires.  I would also suggest stroop and Simon tasks, although my first bet would be Go/NoGo as well.

Comment: Go/NoGo is good for neuroscientific research which measure moments, but I am looking for something whicha are measuring past in much wider sense.

Comment: All for its uses :) Though if you want to implement some sort of training paradigm or look at small group differences, adding a stop signal task might give more sensitivity. And to the go/nogo users out there, stop signal task is regarded as the more "pure"/valid option, regarding inhibition. See the later articles by logan/verbruggen.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider more fundamental personality differences such as Conscientiousness, "...the personality trait of being careful, or vigilant. Conscientiousness implies a desire to do a task well, and to take obligations to others seriously. Conscientious people tend to be efficient and organized as opposed to easy-going and disorderly. They exhibit a tendency to show self-discipline, act dutifully, and aim for achievement; they display planned rather than spontaneous behavior; and they are generally dependable." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscientiousness

It can be measured along with other major personality factors in the Big Five Inventory (BFI): https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~johnlab/bfi.htm